# How to remove hover effect for some of the cells in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using angularjs and following is my css

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

td {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 2px solid gray;
}

td:hover {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: gray;
}

.active {
    border: 2px solid lightgreen;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.booked {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.no_seat {
    padding: 0em;
    border: 2px white;
    background-color: white;
}

.filled {
    background-color: teal;
}
```

I want to remove td:hover effect if it is no_seat I removed the border for the cells if no_seat by resetting padding and border but dont know how to remove the hover effect.

following is my index.html

```
<div ng-app="bookYourSeatApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
    <label>Persons <select ng-model="ctrl.selectedCount" ng-change="ctrl.seats.setAvailCount(ctrl.selectedCount)" ng-options="count as count.val for count in ctrl.selectionCount"></select></label>
    Seats left: {{ctrl.seats.availCount}}<br/>
    Seats selected: {{ctrl.seats.checkedSeats}}<br/>
    <table ng-repeat="(key, rang) in ctrl.seats.map">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rang.seats">
            <td  ng-repeat="seat in row" ng-class="{'active': seat.checked, 'booked': seat.status == 'UNAVAILABLE', 'no_seat': seat.status == 'NO_SEAT', 'filled': seat.status == 'FILLED'}" ng-click="ctrl.seats.select({rang:key, row:row, seat: seat}, ctrl.selectedCount)">
                {{seat.caption}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: use td..no_seat:hover

Comment: `td:not(.no_seat):hover {  cursor: default;  background-color: gray;  }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [**`:not`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class.

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, **:not(X)**, is a functional notation
>   **taking a simple selector** X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector.

---

Change this:

```
td:hover {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

To this:

```
td:not(.no_seat):hover {
 cursor: default;
 background-color: gray; 
}
```

Comment: Nice solution.  What would it look like if - for example - there were multiple classes that were desired to *not* have the hover effect?

Comment: Also - shouldn't it be `td:not(.no_seat):hover`? (Note the colon just before `hover`...)

Comment: @cale_b It was a typo sorry. Sadly, the `:not` pseudo-class only accepts simple selectors. You would need to use multiple pseudo-classes. Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/bavfuf4v/).

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question properly, this can be done simply with pure css.

Combine your css selectors:

```
td:hover {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: gray;
}

.no_seat {
    padding: 0em;
    border: 2px white;
    background-color: white;
}

/* this will control the "no_seat" hovered styles */
td.no_seat:hover {
    background-color: white;
    /* any other styles you want here */
}
```

As @ricky_ruiz points out in his answer, you could also use the `:not()` pseudo-selector, but IMO that could get complicated if you had other classes you wanted it to *not* affect...